# SQL Server BULK INSERT command insert data unordered as of File

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Server `BULK INSERT` to upload a file into a `TEMP` table. I have to use a stored procedure which will be called from MyBatis.

Here is full detail step-by-step:

Procedure `MA060E_ITEM_IMPORT_PROC`:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('MA060E_ITEM_IMPORT_PROC','P') IS NOT NULL
    DROP PROCEDURE MA060E_ITEM_IMPORT_PROC;
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE MA060E_ITEM_IMPORT_PROC
    @filePath   NVARCHAR(100),
    @userId     NVARCHAR(16),
    @kinoId     NVARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @bulk_insert_exec_sql NVARCHAR(1100);

    IF OBJECT_ID('#TEMPTBL_FOR_FILE') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE #TEMPTBL_FOR_FILE;

    CREATE TABLE #TEMPTBL_FOR_FILE
    (
        DATA NVARCHAR(MAX)
    );

    SET @bulk_insert_exec_sql = 'BULK INSERT #TEMPTBL_FOR_FILE FROM' + CHAR(39) + @filePath + CHAR(39) + ' WITH (FIRSTROW = 7,KEEPNULLS)'; --(FIELDTERMINATOR = ' + CHAR(39) + '|' + CHAR(39) + ')';
    EXEC(@bulk_insert_exec_sql);

    SELECT * FROM #TEMPTBL_FOR_FILE ;
END
```

I call this procedure:

```
EXEC MA060E_ITEM_IMPORT_PROC @filePath = 'E:\myproc\YEM_Item_Data_20150206_40MB.TXT', @userId = 'j', @kinoId = 'MA071B'
```

File : `YEM_Item_Data_20150206_40MB.TXT`

```
2015/02/06                    Material Plant Data List                       1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Material Plant Data List
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|Material   |Material Description                    |MRPC|SPT|ValCl|
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|8dsewre|8dsewre|mrpc9|50|7900|
|ITem01|Item01|mrpci|50|7920|
|ITem02|Item02|mrpci|50|7920|
|CA0000w   |BAR CODE LABEL       JAN AV             |SM0 |50 |7900 |
|CA00002   |BAR CODE LABEL       JAN AV             |SM0 |50 |7900 |
|CA0000d   |BAR CODE LABEL       JAN AV             |SM0 |50 |7900 |
.
.
.
Total 599849 Lines
```

I want to get data into `#TEMPTBL_FOR_FILE` table as it is in that file. But when I run this procedure, it gives me undesired results. Data is not ordered as in file.

Sample output:

First run:

[image: Data At First Run]

Second run:

[image: Data At Second run]

Likewise, every time it giving different data.

What should I do so that I get data as it is in the file?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642928/sql-server-table-is-sorted-by-default) - data in a table isn't sorted.  You have to specify a sort order (based on the data in the table) when querying  otherwise the results may be returned in any order.

Comment: In a SQL Server table, **there is no ordering** (no default or system-given ordering). If you need an order, you **must explicitly specify** an `ORDER BY` when you select from that table

Comment: data in relation is generally speaking unordered (or appear to be in some natural order)

Comment: i know about ordering, but problem is, that file will come from some other system, so ordering of data is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can figure out to get the data as ordered into a table is to have a table with identity column, and then use that in the order by clause. I haven't tried, but I would assume it's possible to do this using format file with bulk insert so that you'll only load the data to the text column. Using a view would also be possible but not with temp. tables.